# Como atualizar a branch master a partir de outra branch?

Tags: git

Estou trabalhando em uma `branch` chamada `start/admin/status` eu quero trazer todos as alterações que estão na `branch master` por conta do projeto não tem mais certos pacotes, como faço isso?

Comment: Não seria fazer o merge entre os branchs?

Comment: Não sei, estou aprendendo ainda sobre o git, mas deu certo aqui. dei um `git pul origin master` e resolveu.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer o pull de uma outra branch (no seu caso, a master), desde que a branch remota **não apresente conflitos** com a sua branch local, possibilitando assim o merge *fast-forward*.

Portanto, basta dar o comando `git pull` seguido do nome do repositório remoto e branch:

```
git pull <repositorio> <nome-branch>
```

No seu caso, ficaria:

```
git pull origin master
```

Se ocorrer conflitos, você precisará fazer o `checkout` para a branch master e fazer o git pull de lá mesmo, resolvendo os conflitos:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```